# how to display comments on post

Tags: php, mysqli

I've small blog users can add new post and others can comment on this post ( Post is working perfectly, comments is working too )

all posts is showing and all comment is showing but each Separated , how can I display it related.

```
function getPostInfoo(){
  if($this->num_members < 0){
    $q = "SELECT * FROM ".TBL_POSTS;
    $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $q);
    $fields = array();

    while($fetch=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "
        <h3>".$fetch['post']."</h3>
        <p>".$fetch['username']."</p>";
    }
    $this->num_members = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  }
  //return
  return $fields;
}
function getComment(){

  $q = "SELECT ".TBL_POSTS.".*, ".TBL_COMMENTS.".*
         FROM ".TBL_POSTS."
         INNER JOIN ".TBL_COMMENTS." ON ".TBL_COMMENTS.".postid=".TBL_POSTS.".postid";
  $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $q);
  /* Error occurred, return given name by default */
  if(!$result || (mysqli_num_rows($result) < 1)){
     return NULL;
  }
  $fields = array();
  while($fetch=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
      $fields[] = "<p><a href='#'>".$fetch['username'].": </a>".$fetch['comment']."<br>
                      <small class='text-muted'>".$fetch['cmntdate']."</small>
                    </p>

      ";
   }
  /* Return result array */
  return $fields;
 }
```

test.php

```
echo "<div>";
$myList2 = $database->getPostInfoo();
if (is_array($myList2) || is_object($myList2)){
  foreach($myList2 as $arrayItem2){
    echo $arrayItem2;

  }
}else {
     echo      "No Posts yet.";
}
echo "</div>
<div>";
$myList = $database->getComment();
if (is_array($myList) || is_object($myList)){
    foreach($myList as $arrayItem){
        echo $arrayItem;
    }
}else {
   echo "No comments yet.";
}

<form method='post' action='functions.php' method='POST'>
<div class='form-group' >
    <textarea class='form-control' name = 'comment' placeholder='Write Comment'></textarea>
    <input type='hidden' name='postid' value='1'>
    <input type='hidden' name='comment_sub' value='1'>
    <input type='submit' value='Add Comment!'>
</div>
</form>

</div>";
```

what I need to do is to display each comments on its own post & show comment textarea on each post

**Please see the image**  https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4D55.jpg

Comment: Have you made any attempt to "display it related"?

Comment: yes I've try to put `foreach` inside each other but its not showing any difference, which means its not working

Comment: You have a parse error in this `echo "</div>";
<div>";` - Edit: See the below comment.

Comment: Enable error reporting. You should be getting an `unexpected <`..... - Edit: You deleted the comment I was responding to. Edit: and now you edited, again. Please, be careful when posting code. It could have been closed as a parse error.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner sorry its not error (when i was writing this question I delete `echo` by mistake), code dose not have any error,

Answer (score 0):

You need to be getting one post at a time and then fetch its comments.

So your **test.php** should look this **test.php?id=post_id**

Where **post_id** is the unique identifier of your post based on your db structure

Could be e.g is 1 or 2 or if  you are using auto-increment id

Then you can add the following code to at the beginning of your **test.php** to get the post id

```
$post_id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '';
```

The fetch the post and it's comment from your table using the value of **$post_id**

Hope it helps

Comment: I know this, but what if I want to show all posts and its comments in one blog ? which I have one blog now and this blog have many posts and each post have some comments (each user can come to this blog can see posts and comments and he can add post and comments)

Comment: Ohk so within your **foreach loop** get the post id from it and the run the comment function under it with your extra comment box.  What you're currently doing is fetching all the posts, then the comments, then the comment box. All should be in your forecah loop

Comment: Exactly, that what I want to do , but try several times and not working as expected

Comment: I've try this but not worked  [link](https://imgur.com/a/PcFakgf)

Answer (score -1):

Try this function:

```
function getPostsInfo(){
$q = "SELECT ".TBL_POSTS.".`id`,".TBL_POSTS.".`post`, ".TBL_POSTS.".`username`, ".TBL_COMMENTS.".`username` as comment_username, ".TBL_COMMENTS.".`comment`, ".TBL_COMMENTS.".`cmntdate` 
     FROM ".TBL_POSTS."
     LEFT JOIN ".TBL_COMMENTS." ON ".TBL_COMMENTS.".postid=".TBL_POSTS.".postid";
$result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $q);
$posts = [];
while($fetch=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    if(isset($posts[$fetch["id"]])){
        $posts[$fetch["id"]]["comments"][] = [
            "username" => $fetch["comment_username"],
            "comment" => $fetch["comment"],
            "cmntdate" => $fetch["cmntdate"]
        ];
    }else{
        $posts[$fetch["id"]] = [
            "post" => $fetch["post"],
            "username" => $fetch["username"],
            "comments" => [[
                "username" => $fetch["comment_username"],
                "comment" => $fetch["comment"],
                "cmntdate" => $fetch["cmntdate"]
            ]]

        ];
    }
}
return $posts;
```

}

Comment: Notice: Array to string conversion

Comment: From which row?

Comment: `$myList = $database->getPostsInfoo();
if (is_array($myList) || is_object($myList)){foreach($myList as $arrayItem){echo $arrayItem;}  
}else {echo "No comments";}`  error is **echo $arrayItem;**

Comment: for each loop in test.php

Comment: See result from this: echo "<pre>"; print_r(getPostsInfo()); And you should create new view

Comment: this is ok its showing everything related in array ( how can I make it like normal view) ?

Comment: `foreach($database->getPostInfoo() as $post) {
    echo "
        <h3>".$post['post']."</h3>
        <p>".$post['username']."</p>";
    foreach($post["comments"] as $comment){
        echo "<p><a href='#'>".$comment['username'].": </a>".$comment['comment']."<br>
                      <small class='text-muted'>".$comment['cmntdate']."</small>
                    </p>

      ";
    }
}`

Comment: its display everything as expected but  this error showing `Notice: Undefined index: post `  and  `Notice: Undefined index: username` , they point to first foreach `echo " <h3>".$post['post']."</h3> <p>".$post['username']."</p>";`

Comment: I've edit your function code , I've add this **`echo "<p>".$fetch["comment"]."</p>";`** to first condition after the array

Comment: and I've add this code in second condition **(else)** `echo "<p><h1>".$fetch["post"]."</h1><a href='#'>".$fetch["username"]."</a><br><p>".$fetch["comment"]."</p>";**` after the array

Comment: If I delete `<p>".$fetch["comment"]."</p>"` from second code condition its now showing first comment **(it always display all comments Except first comment)**